# Page variables onclick to trigger audio clip

Tags: jquery, css, html5-audio

I need a little help with a script to trigger an audio clip.  On the page there are five icons.  Once all five of them have been clicked, an audio clip is supposed to play.   Here is the image below:

[image]

Here is the html:

```
<div class="slide overlay-container" id="inter8">
    <div class="container content box-middle slide-back8">
        <audio data-autoplay>
            <source src="audio/mars_glm_intro_slide05a.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>

        <div class="row zero">
            <div class="top txt-ctr">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                    <img src="images/Icon.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Icons and bars -->
        <div class="row zero">
            <div class="mdl txt-ctr hght txt-white">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 mar"></div>

                <!-- Blue -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 icn1 btn1" tabindex="1">
                    <img src="images/Icon1.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 blu mar">
                    Recruit and<br>
                    Onboard<br>
                    current and<br>
                    future Associates
                </div>
                <!-- Green -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 icn2 btn2" tabindex="1">
                    <img src="images/Icon2.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 green mar">
                    Maximize<br>
                    Performance<br>
                    of Associates
                </div>
                <!-- Purple -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 icn3 btn3" tabindex="1">
                    <img src="images/Icon3.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 purple mar">
                    Engage<br>
                    Associates
                </div>
                <!-- Orange -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 icn4 btn4" tabindex="1">
                    <img src="images/Icon4.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 orange mar">
                    Develop<br>
                    Associates
                </div>
                <!-- Yellow -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 icn5 btn5" tabindex="1">
                    <div class="play">
                        <img src="images/Icon5.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 yellow mar">
                    All in the<br>
                    Mars Way
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row page8-btm zero">
            <div class="btm">
                <h2>What is Great Line Management?</h2>
                <p>Click the icons to learn more.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the script:

```
var click1 = false;
var click2 = false;
var click3 = false;
var click4 = false;
var click5 = false;

$('.btnClass').click(checkProg);

function checkProg(){
    var thisBtn = $(this).attr('id');

    if(thisBtn == "btn1") {
        click1 = true;
    } else if (thisBtn == "btn2") {
        click2 = true;
    } else if (thisBtn == "btn3") {
        click3 = true;
    } else if (thisBtn == "btn4") {
        click4 = true;
    } else if (thisBtn == "btn5") {
        click5 = true;
    }

    if(click1 == true && click2 == true && click3 ==  true && click4 ==  true && click5 ==  true) {
        'audio/mars_glm_intro_slide05b.mp3'
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any script errors.  So, obviously I am overlooking something.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's your `.btnClass`?

Comment: You're not actually doing anything in the `if` statement - just defining a headless string literal. Presumably you need to call `play()` on the `audio` element in there instead

Comment: What do you expect this to do on it's own or are you not sharing all the code? `'audio/mars_glm_intro_slide05b.mp3'`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. Let me explain:

1) You are processing clicks for elements with a class called .btnClass but that class is not assigned to any of the elements you are showing in the code.

2) You check the ID of the element clicked and search for the attribute ID but the btnX value is added as a class not as the ID.

This code does what you need:

```
<div class="slide overlay-container" id="inter8">
        <div class="container content box-middle slide-back8">
        <audio data-autoplay>
        <source src="audio/mars_glm_intro_slide05a.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>

            <div class="row zero">
                <div class="top txt-ctr">
                   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><img src="images/Icon.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;">
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Icons and bars -->   
            <div class="row zero"><div class="mdl txt-ctr hght txt-white">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 mar">

                </div>

               <!-- Blue --> 
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 icn1" tabindex="1">                 <img id="btn1"  src="images/Icon1.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;" class="imgClicker">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 blu mar">Recruit and<br>
                    Onboard<br>
                    current and<br>
                    future Associates
                </div>
                <!-- Green -->  
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 icn2" tabindex="1">   <img id="btn2" src="images/Icon2.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;" class="imgClicker">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 green mar">Maximize<br>
                    Performance<br>
                    of Associates
                </div>
                <!-- Purple -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 icn3" tabindex="1"><img id="btn3" src="images/Icon3.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;" class="imgClicker">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 purple mar">Engage<br>
                    Associates
                </div>
                <!-- Orange -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 icn4" tabindex="1"><img id="btn4" src="images/Icon4.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;" class="imgClicker">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 orange mar">Develop<br>
                    Associates
                </div>
                <!-- Yellow -->
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 icn5" tabindex="1"><div class="play"><img id="btn5" src="images/Icon5.png" style="width:150px; height:93px;" class="imgClicker"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 yellow mar">All in the<br>
                    Mars Way
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row page8-btm zero"><div class="btm">
                <h2>What is Great Line Management?</h2>
                <p>Click the icons to learn more.</p></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
 var click1 = false;
    var click2 = false;
    var click3 = false;
    var click4 = false;
    var click5 = false;

     $('.imgClicker').click(checkProg);

     function checkProg(){
     var thisBtn = $(this).attr('id');

     if(thisBtn == "btn1"){
      click1 = true;
     }else if (thisBtn == "btn2"){
     click2 = true;
     }else if (thisBtn == "btn3"){
     click3 = true;
     }else if (thisBtn == "btn4"){
     click4 = true;
     }else if (thisBtn == "btn5"){
     click5 = true;
     }

     if(click1 == true && click2 == true && click3 ==  true && click4 ==  true && click5 ==  true){
     alert('Play that song!');
     var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
     audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.soundjay.com/misc/sounds/bell-ringing-01.mp3');
     audioElement.play();


     }

 }
```

There is also a working Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w9szhtd5/5/)